# English word for days/weeks/months where there is a skip between each days/weeks/month?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm looking for an English word (phrase) to be used when someone wants to mentioned days/weeks/months/year ... where there is a space or skipped days/weeks... between each two.

** For example:** let say we have 10 days and I want to say only Day#1, Day#3, ..., Day#9 or (#2, #4, ..., #10).

Comment: I think most people would say "every other" day/week/month...or maybe "alternate" days etc.

Comment: @Andrew Leach, while the question is not entirely clear, it should be noted that it says 'skipped day**s** / week**s**', which seems to imply that the OP is interested in the terms (if there are any) for *once every three days*, *once every four days*, etc., as well as for *once every two days*. If this interpretation of the question is correct, then it is not a duplicate, as the other question is only about *once every two days*.